# Conditions with Nice Young's function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, convex-analysis

How the conditions of Theorem 1.7 in http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm110/sm11014.pdf would look like if $\Phi_1(t)=t^p$ and $\Phi_2(t)=t^q$, with $1<p\leq q< \infty$ and $\Phi$ is an $N$-function (Nice Young Fucntion).

Note, the parameters $t, u,v, w$ are in $\mathbb R_+$ in the above theorem.

Comment: $\Phi_2 \circ \Phi_1$ convex is the same as $q \ge p$.  For the other conditions, you need to know what $t$, $u$, $v$, $w$, and $k$ are.

Comment: I meant $\Phi_1 \circ \Phi_2^{-1}$ in the previous comment.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: Thank you. I forgot to mention-  the $t,u,v,w$ are in $R_+$.

Comment: I meant that you really need formulas for them.  But I do notice that the $\lambda$s cancel out.  Otherwise they aren't much cleaner in your special case.

Comment: Yes, the lambdas are canceled out, but I am still stuck on how to rewrite those conditions for my special case.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  You simply write them out.

Comment: The constant $C$ will come out of the integral.  So each condition could be rewritten as $\sup_x \text{stuff} < \infty$.